# Css hamburger - не работает в мобильных браузерах

Tags: jquery, css

Есть такая адаптивная менюшка, гамбургер основан на :after/:before элементах. Вроде бы мобильные браузеры поддерживают эти псевдоэлементы http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Aafter, но верхняя и нижняя палочка не трансформируются, словно поворот на 45 градусов не работает `transform: rotate(45deg);`.

Проверял в Opera, UC Browser, Android browser - остается только средняя палочка при клике. Что не так?

Код:

```js
$(function() {
  //адаптивное главное меню сайта
  var siteMenu = $('.region-menu'),
    siteMenuLink = $('<a id="touch-region-menu" href="#"><span></span>Меню</a>');

  siteMenuLink.insertBefore(siteMenu);

  createSiteMenu();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    createSiteMenu();
  });

  $(siteMenuLink).on('click', clickSiteMenu);

  function clickSiteMenu(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    siteMenu.slideToggle('fast');
  }

  function createSiteMenu() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    if (w > 767 && siteMenu.is(':hidden')) {
      siteMenu.removeAttr('style');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.region-menu {
  display: none;
}
#touch-region-menu {
  background: #69c none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  height: 43px;
  line-height: 39px;
  padding-left: 37px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#touch-region-menu span,
#touch-region-menu span:before,
#touch-region-menu span:after {
  background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 1px;
  content: "";
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
}
#touch-region-menu span:before {
  top: -6px;
}
#touch-region-menu span:after {
  bottom: -6px;
}
#touch-region-menu span {
  left: -22px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}
#touch-region-menu span,
#touch-region-menu span:before,
#touch-region-menu span:after {
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}
#touch-region-menu.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#touch-region-menu.active span:before,
#touch-region-menu.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#touch-region-menu.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#touch-region-menu.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="region-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>1 категория</li>
    <li>2 категория</li>
    <li>3 категория</li>
    <li>4 категория</li>
    <li>5 категория</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте префиксы и все заработает [пример 1](http://altdrama.ru/), [пример 2](http://www.isk-soyuz.ru/)

[Вырванный пример и перенесенный на codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NrPgoL)

```
 -moz-transform:    rotate(15deg);
 -o-transform:      rotate(45deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 transform:         rotate(45deg);

 -webkit-transition: prop time;
 -moz-transition: prop time;
 -ms-transition: prop time;
 -o-transition: prop time;
 transition: prop time;
```

В качестве дополнения
http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/84141)

Comment: да, действительно заработало, сенкс.

Comment: @totorro если я исправлю ответ, минус исчезнет?

Comment: @Jarvis у Вас 2 минуса и один плюс. Само по себе исправление ответа минус не уберет, но сподвигнет других пользовтелей ставить вам плюсы. Например если все будет ок - я плюсануи выйдете в ноль

Comment: @Jarvis вместо ссылок на сайты пожалуйста приведите небольшой пример кода прямо здесь. Сайты когда-нибудь перепишут а то и совсем закроют, и тогда ответ потеряет смысл.

Comment: А вот ссылка на шпаргалку - полезная. Но только как дополнение к ответу )

Comment: Сделал, все для вас